# Length shows as 497 instead of 562 due to Unicode; how to get real length?

Tags: javascript

The following string shows a length of `497`, whereas it's actually `562` characters:

```
alert('[**BFI/KBFI**](http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/?station_ids=KBFI&std_trans=translated&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&chk_tafs=on&submitmet=Submit): Boeing Field King County International Airport \u2022 **Observed:** 55 mins ago \u2022 **Wind:** 170\u00B0/S @ 12 kts \u2022 **Visibility:** 10.0mi/16.09km \u2022 **Sky (AGL):** Few clouds @ 1,800ft; Broken clouds @ 2,600ft; Overcast @ 3,600ft \u2022 **Temperature:** 10.6\u00B0C/51\u00B0F \u2022 **Dewpoint:** 6.7\u00B0C/44\u00B0F \u2022 **Pressure:** 29.70" Hg/1,006mb \u2022 **Conditions:** MVFR'.length);
```

There's a difference of 65 characters, which I believe is caused by the Unicode characters, e.g. the degrees symbol `\u00B0`.

I need the length outputted to be shown as total character literals; how can I fix this?

Here's the string on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7ahe/).

Comment: You can't. To javascript, \uxxxx is one character, period, end of discussion. You'd have to do \\uxxxx, and then it wouldn't be a degree sign any longer.

Comment: this is only a problem with literals, if you ajax'd the text it would be fine and you could get the escaped length.

Comment: "Can't" is wrong, I could always iterate each char and count, if anything, but it seems wrong to do that.

Comment: No you can't. If you iterate over chars, your iteration will see \uxxxx as One Character.

Comment: your text is over-encoded, but you can get a closer idea than mere str.length by looking at the JSON.stringify(str).length instead, which with your text shows 500. if you want the actual byte weight of a string, you have to use  a weird encodeURIComponent routine.

Comment: @dandavis Over-encoded how? SO's chat mandates I send unicode symbols escaped like that, otherwise they come out wrong. 500 is not correct. The literal length is 562.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: i mean over-encoded according to javascript, not SO...

Comment: You don't need to use such a long string to demo the problem, this will do:  **Temperature:** 10.6\u00B0C/51\u00B0F    \u00B0 is the degree character °, it's not 6 characters, it's just 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... you have a string. It has some 'interesting' Unicode. You are passing it to someone else's code that chooses to represent it with some \u escapes. Once it has those escapes in place, some other code goes and rejects it as too long, counting the escapes.

You can't solve this by asking the poor Javascript interpreter for 'length', because, *at that point*, those Unicode characters are, really, single characters. You need to know the length after this other code goes and expands into a representation with escapes.

A smart commenter suggested that `JSON.stringify(str).length` might be a good enough approximation.

Comment: I'm not passing it to someone else's code that represents it with `\u` characters, *I* am representing it like that, because raw Unicode symbols show up with the wrong encoding in chat. SO chat, if anything, counts the length wrongly. I need a workaround for the bug.

Comment: So, here you have a workaround, replicated in an answer and a comment.

Comment: You're not representing it like that. If you were, it would print as \\uxxxx and length would count that as 6.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem was that `:123456` gets prepended to the message, putting it to 503; 3 over the 500 max chars. It was unrelated to Unicode. Sorry about that guys, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 4):

The length *is* 497.  The string literal is interpreted long before your code can figure it out.  The actual string representation in memory contains those unicode characters.

If you want things like `\u00b0` to be interpreted literally, escape your backslash with an extra backslash.

Comment: When pasted into a Stack Exchange chat room, it's treated as too long. I **need** the literal length.

Comment: @DannyBeckett What are you talking about?  What you paste in a Stack Exchange chat isn't a JavaScript string literal being interpreted by the JavaScript interpreter... it's just a string.

Comment: It's for a bot. Join me in [Aviation Chat Bot Testing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12308/aviation-chat-bot-testing) if you like.

Comment: @DannyBeckett What's for a bot?

Comment: We're going to need to see the code that does the 'paste', then.

Comment: It's Zirak's [SO-ChatBot](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot), the bot that runs in all/most rooms

Comment: @DannyBeckett What are you talking about?  What does a bot have to do with a string literal in your code?

Comment: The bot is written in JS. When that code is sent to a room, it's deemed as too long, because SO treats it by literal length.

Comment: @DannyBeckett What's your point?  You aren't listening to what I'm telling you.  When you type in a string literal, what you type is interpreted.  What you have in memory in a string is already there.  These are different things.

Comment: @Brad Please are you able to come to chat for a few minutes? The error is very easily demonstrated there.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I went to your chat earlier.  Will you re-read what I've posted, and what everyone else has posted?  The answer is right in front of you.

Comment: @Brad Bret Copeland's just figured out the answer. It's not this. But it's also not due to Unicode. `args.directreply()` (which sends the message to the room) prepends a message ID, like `:123456`; that's what puts the message over max chars. I hadn't considered that, and assumed it was due to Unicode; I was wrong.